# HTML template with PHP code

Tags: typo3

I have written an extension with a html template. Inside that html template there is php code. That php code dynamically generates some DOM elements **depending on files and folders in fileadmin**! Now if I change files and folders in fileadmin and THEN go to my website, the html template of my extension hasn't changed. That means the DOM elements are still the same. Thus the php code hasn't been executed again and typo3 must have used some cached version of my html template. Where can I configure that behaviour and force typo3 to always recalculate my html template (meaning: execute the php code in it!)?

Comment: Why did you take away the typo3 information, flimzy? Now everybody is confused about me talking about things like "extension" and "fildeadmin"?

Comment: Your question is tagged with `typo3`, so it is published in the TYPO3 slack-channel and everyone will know about it. But you also should tag the correct version and mention the kind of template.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned: TYPO3 uses a lot of caches.

And if something depends on external activities it should be uncached on all levels.
So you need to declare your plugin uncached.

you have not explained what kind of template you use. In case of Fluid templates you might use uncached partials and viewhelpers.